# Android app doesn't work properly on devices running new versions of Android

Tags: android, qt, sdk, qml, qt-creator

Using the tools below on *Qt Creator 5.9.0* (*Qt 5.12.3*), created a simple QML game for Android devices.

[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nB0F.jpg), *JDK*: **jdk1.8.0_211**, *NDK*: **android-ndk-r19c**, *Gradle*: **5.4**, *ADB*: **1.0.40**.

The game works properly on Windows, Mac, iOS and even a tablet running Android version 4.4.2, "but" on devices with higher versions of Android, say 7, 8 or 9, it stops and freezes at the middle of working!

I personally assume the issue is either related to my SDK or the code (but the strange thing is that, it works well on those many different platform mentioned above!).

What could be the reason for that problem in your points of view, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did your try if you can reproduce it while running in a debugger? I assume you use 5.12.3 also for r the application? ( The QT version of the QT Creator itself doesn't make a difference here)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was hiding inside the code. A line of code was the source of the issue. I'd created a component and used its ID later on. Then removed the component for some reason but had forgotten to remove its ID too. By removing it. the issue was solved.